# OpenVPN private domain unsing DNSMasq

Tags: openvpn, dnsmasq

What I want to do is to set up OpenVPN network which would make it possible to access private domain ( a.domain, b.domain, d.domain). I believe the simplest way to do it is to use *dnsmasq* to resolve *domain* to 10.8.0.1. It seems to be working fine on the host, I tried to `ping domain` and it worked. However I have some difficulties setting up clients, I tried to connect from my Ubuntu PC which has *network-manager-openvpn* and set DNS server to 10.8.0.1, sometimes it does work, sometimes it does not. And I don't really know why.

On Windows 7 machine with *OpenVPN GUI* I didn't manage to make it resolve domain name. In OpenVPN server.conf I added `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"` and `push "dhcp-option DOMAIN domain"`.

My main concern is to make it easy to set up clients on different platforms so they could access private network using private domain name, because I want to create different *apache* virtual hosts. And I thing manual DNS configuration on client side would complicate it too much.

If you have any suggestions how I could achieve this please share your ideas. Maybe there is other way to achieve this (without OpenVPN or dnsmasq)?